# How to create an instance of an ecore file programmatically

Tags: eclipse, emf, xtend, ecore

I am trying to create an instance of an ecore file so I can store data in it. I will serialize it and store it as XMI (and then load it if it exist). 
In my case I cannot use genmodel and "create dynamic instance". I found [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/29093/0/page/2#comment_form) which create the ecore model itself programmatically, but I want to load an ecore file and then create an instance of it using some general factory.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

you may have a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-dynamicemf/index.html

(with the difference of getting the eclasses and estructural features by reading the ecore)

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial they use [ResourceSet.createResource()](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ResourceSet.html#createResource(org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI)) to create a new resource.

If you want to load an existing resource, you should try [ResourceSet.getResource()](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ResourceSet.html#getResource(org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI,%20boolean)).